# Display Table from Postgres in jsp

Tags: java, postgresql, servlets, jakarta-ee

I want to display table in jsp.

Static content is fine but table doesn't show.
I want to do it in MVC, I don't want to use java code in jsp

#### DbConnetion

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

public class DbConnection {
    Connection db_conn;
    public Connection getConnection()
    {
        try {
            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver").newInstance();
            String url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/testowaaplikacja";
            String user = "postgres";
            String pass = "password";
                db_conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,pass);  
                if((db_conn != null)&&(!db_conn.isClosed()))
            {
                System.out.println("Connected...");
            }
            return db_conn;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            //System.out.println("Error in connecting to database ");
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

#### Model

```
public class KsiegaWieczysta {

    private long nrksiegi;
    private String adres;
    private long nrdzialki;

    public long getNrksiegi() {
        return nrksiegi;
    }

    public void setNrksiegi(long nrksiegi) {
        this.nrksiegi = nrksiegi;
    }

    public String getAdres() {
        return adres;
    }

    public void setAdres(String adres) {
        this.adres = adres;
    }

    public long getNrdzialki() {
        return nrdzialki;
    }

    public void setNrdzialki(long nrdzialki) {
        this.nrdzialki = nrdzialki;
    }

}
```

#### DAO

```
public class KsiegiDAO {

    private static DbConnection db1;
    private static Connection connection;

    public List<KsiegaWieczysta> getReleaseData() {
        List<KsiegaWieczysta> ksiegi = new ArrayList<KsiegaWieczysta>();
        ResultSet resultSet = null;
        Statement statement = null;

        try {
            db1 = new DbConnection();
            connection = db1.getConnection();

            String query = "SELECT nrksiegi, address, nrdzialki FROM ksiegi";
            statement = connection.createStatement();
            resultSet = statement.executeQuery(query);

            {
                while (resultSet.next()) {
                    KsiegaWieczysta ksiega = new KsiegaWieczysta();
                    ksiega.setNrksiegi(resultSet.getLong("nrksiegi"));
                    ksiega.setAdres(resultSet.getString("address"));
                    ksiega.setNrdzialki(resultSet.getLong("nrdzialki"));
                    ksiegi.add(ksiega);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (resultSet != null) {
                try {
                    resultSet.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if (statement != null) {
                try {
                    statement.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if (connection != null) {
                try {
                    connection.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }

        return ksiegi;
    }
}
```

#### Servlet

```
@WebServlet("/showtable")
public class ShowTable extends HttpServlet {

    KsiegiDAO ksiegiDAO = new KsiegiDAO();

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        List<KsiegaWieczysta> ksiegi = ksiegiDAO.getReleaseData();
        request.setAttribute("ksiegi", ksiegi); // Will be available as
                                                    // ${ksiegi} in JSP
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/showtable.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }


}
```

#### JSP

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
Hello
<table>
    <c:forEach items="${ksiegi}" var="ksiega">
        <tr>
            <td><c:out value="${ksiega.nrksiegi}" /></td>
            <td><c:out value="${ksiega.adres}" /></td>
            <td><c:out value="${ksiega.nrdzialki}" /></td>

        </tr>
    </c:forEach>

</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for help

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Or it just doesn't display?

Comment: Also, have you printed the results of your sql query, so that you know the KsiegaWieczysta object properties aren't null?

Comment: In console im getting Conected... and it just doesnt display

Comment: just before `ksiegi.add(ksiega);` in your DAO, print `ksiega.getNrksiegi()` so you can verify the object properties

Comment: yes is showing data from sql "Connected...
1029
9332
10029
12930
12344
19288
109349
99481
1237471
19384817"
but got this error https://gyazo.com/1fcb6c6bf22176cf3b8a47560134367f

Comment: So the "/WEB-INF/showtable.jsp" file doesnt' exist? The error is quite clear on this. Perhaps you placed it in wrong folder or typo'ed the filename?

Comment: He said the static content is showing up but the table is not. That means he sees "Insert title here" when he loads the page.

Comment: @dev_feed: I was referring to screenshot linked in his last comment.

Comment: @BalusC sorry, missed that part of his comment. good catch.